# Redundancy through constructor initialization

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization

I have two class that uses the logger.

```
public class FooClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IBarClass _barClass;

    public FooClass() : this (new Logger(), new BarClass())
    { }

    public FooClass(ILogger logger, IBarClass barClass)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _barClass = barClass;
    }

    public void FooMethod()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

public class BarClass : IBarClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public BarClass() : this (new Logger())
    { }

    private BarClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void BarMethod()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

It seems that logger is initialized twice in FooClass and BarClass. Can't I use the logger initialized in FooClass to be used in BarClass. Are there any other solutions for this problem.

Please note that the instance of FooClass must be made through empty constructor call. (This example is the exact simple version of the problem I am facing)

Comment: use IoC container like structuremap http://docs.structuremap.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface ILogger { }
class Logger : ILogger { }

interface IBarClass { }
class BarClass : IBarClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public BarClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void BarMethod()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

class FooClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IBarClass _barClass;

    public FooClass()
    {
        _logger = new Logger();
        _barClass = new BarClass(_logger);
    }

    public FooClass(ILogger logger, IBarClass barClass)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _barClass = barClass;
    }

    public void FooMethod()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What if `FooClass` is removed in future ? It seems that the `logger` initialization is dependent on the `FooClass`. Is there any way through which we have both `FooClass` and `BarClass` and only one instance of `Logger` class which is sent to the constructors of both `FooClass` and `BarClass` ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed: are you sure, that OP really needs what are you talking about? I can't see this in his question, there's nothing about decoupling of `FooClass`, `BarClass` and `Logger`.

Comment: Sorry, OP doesn't seem to have asked this. By the way, just out in curiosity, how to decouple all these classes?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed: the most obvious way, IMO, is to use IoC-(DI-)container

Comment: @Dennis I have thought of this implementation earlier. Is it the best practices for doing this? Does't it make any problems in future as we are instantiating something within a constructor and using it to instantiate another object.

Comment: @BIKALBHATTARAI: it depends on your requirements. Many types initialize instances of another types in their constructors, it is definitely a common practice. But this way you're getting coupled types hierarchy, nowhewhomustnotbenamed absolutely fairly pointed this. If this is acceptable for you, why not to use it? If you want decoupled types, then dependency injection is what are you looking for.

Comment: @BIKALBHATTARAI: As Dennis answered, if you want to de-couple various classes and keep the code great, you should definitely explore `Dependency injection - Inversion of Control`. Or if you must keep up and running with time, you can use how's its above. All depends upon your requirements.

Comment: @Dennis: thanks Dennis. +1 for DI - IOC. Makes perfect sense.